# Subversion command with curly braces in fish shell

Tags: shell, svn, command, fish

In Bash I can enter the following command.:

```
svn log -r {2015-08-26}:HEAD
```

to get the last commits from `2015-08-26` to `HEAD`. But the command does not work in the fish shell. Then I get the following error:

```
svn: E205000: Syntaxfehler in Revisionsparameter »2015-08-26:HEAD«
```

If I try:

```
svn log -r '\{'2015-08-26'\}':HEAD
```

it does also not work:

```
svn: E205000: Syntaxfehler in Revisionsparameter »\{2015-08-26\}:HEAD«
```

How can I execute that command in the fish shell? Maybe without typing a lot of further charaters like `'\'`.

Comment: Was double escaping the `{` and `}` there intentional? Does using *either* slash escaping *or* `''` escaping work?

Comment: `svn log -r \{2015-08-26\}:HEAD` works also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following command variation works in the fish shell.:

```
svn log -r '{'2015-08-26'}':HEAD
```

Slash escaping does also work:

```
svn log -r \{2015-08-26\}:HEAD
```

Comment: I find quoting the whole argument easiest to type: `svn log -r '{2015-08-26}:HEAD'`